# How to access in Array List model class

Tags: java

This is array list model class. Is it right or wrong? I can not access this class from another class

```
public class CartOrder {
    List<CartOrder.Data> data;

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    class Data {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to edit your post into a more readable version, it's not clear: is the class `Data` an inner class of `CartOrder`

Comment: @daniu "`CartOrder.Data`", so yes

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: "I can not access this class from another class"  make it public

Comment: i want to set Name in inner class of CartOrder from another class .i can not access inner class of CartOrder

Comment: Can you add the source code of the other class, where you want to make that modification?

Comment: how can i data set in setName from another class.how can i create  CartOrder class object .@daniu

Comment: This is another class code from where i want to access model  
   CartOrder cartOrder=new CartOrder();
       cartOrder.setData(); @Dominique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have read the exception properly, then you would have also read the solution to your problem. You need to instantiate `CartOrder` object first on which you then can call `s.new Data()` as seen below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CartOrder s = new CartOrder();
    Data d = s.new Data();
    d.setName("Test");
    s.addData(d);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Modified your existing class:

```
public class CartOrder  {
    List<Data> data;

    public CartOrder () {
        data = new ArrayList<Data>();
    }

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void addData(Data data) {
        this.data.add(data);
    }

    class Data {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: others line is ok but s.addData(d) given exception

Comment: Because I added that method for myself

Comment: so how to inner class data add in array list

Answer (score 0):

[similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private)

But yes your code is accurate. If you make your member property private `Data::name` then it cannot be accessed by anything but the factory class (`class Data`). Same would be true for your other function and its member.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use it like:

```
CartOrder.Data data = new CartOrder.Data();
```

In order for that to work you should make you inner class static, so you code would become

```
public class CartOrder {
    List<CartOrder.Data> data;

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    static class Data {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can use this like:

```
public void someMethodInSomeOtherClass() {
    // ...
    CartOrder cartOrder = new CartOrder();

    CartOrder.Data someData = new CartOrder.Data();
    someData.setName("Luke");

    CartOrder.Data moreData = new CartOrder.Data();
    moreData.setName("Han");

    cartOrder.setData(Arrays.asList(someData, moreData));
    // ...
}
```